# How to add more detail and specifics to work history as per recruiter's request?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, tech-industry

A recruiter working for a recruiting firm reached out to me. She is now saying the account manager wants me to make some stylistic changes to my resume. For example "include more details about the proprietary applications and software I used in my past jobs. Include what systems and software I used in more detail as in explaining what I used and what tech stack was behind the work I was doing".

I've never gotten this feedback before and it's a bit vague to me. Right now my resume is one page so I could add more detail to make it two. Should I ask the recruiter what she means by this? Should I ask for some specific examples? I don't want to add filler but I could add more accomplishments and responsibilities that I don't normally have space to include in one page.

Comment: Prepare a longer master resume. When applying to specific positions, whittle it down to a single page.

Comment: Is this company by any chance European and you are from the US? We don't do "accomplishments and responsibilities" here, we write down what we actually worked on, what technologies and tools we used. That might not be your style, but I cannot find anything vague about the request, they very much spelled out what they want. Can you explain in more detail what you find vague or what is stopping you from doing what they asked?

Comment: This is hard for me without seeing an example of what you have on your original resume. Adding details about proprietary applications seems strange, but talking about the tools and software and tech stack you used at your jobs or in your projects seems reasonable. It helps assess if you know the tools or technologies or similar tools and technologies to those in use at a prospective employer.

Comment: SO they want to know if you are familiar with Azure Devops, or jira, or AWS Cloudformation, or buddy... etc?

Answer (score 5):

They are asking you to put software and technologies you’ve used in your work on your resume so they can more easily match you up with job postings.

A job posting might have a list of things that aren’t required, but are desirable. For example:

> Experience with logical equivalence checkers (e.g., OneSpin 360-EC, ESP, Conformal EC)

If you have used OneSpin, it should be on your resume so that your resume stands out from the resumes of candidates who don’t have that experience.